# Servlet gives 404 instead of loading appropriate page. Console says SEVERE error when launching Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

For some reason **Apache Tomcat 7.0** doesn't run my main servlet(`PlaceListServlet`) that should list a bunch of database items on `place-list.jsp` page.

I keep getting **404** everywhere, and **Eclipse** doesn't report any errors in the source.

What seems to be the problem?

**PlaceListServlet.java** (*main servlet that should load* `place-list.jsp`):

```
package com.myproject.crud;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet({"/place/", "index.jsp"})
public class PlaceListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private PlaceRepositoryImpl placeRepo = new PlaceRepositoryImpl();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("places", placeRepo.listPlaces());
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/place-list.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I just looked at the console and saw this error:

> SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Oct 19, 2012 11:34:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to
>   previous error(s) Oct 19, 2012 11:34:45 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
>   listenerStart Oct 19, 2012 11:34:45 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/GBCPlacesCRUD] startup failed due to previous errors Oct 19, 2012
>   11:34:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Oct 19, 2012 11:34:45 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Oct 19, 2012 11:34:45 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   1096 ms

Comment: Could you please send you web.xml and let us know what is the URL that you tried in the browser.

Comment: Did you make sure that the application is successfully started? Check it using the manager app.

Comment: @Tom
Yes. I right click on the project and select Run As...>Run on Server.

Comment: Clicking doesn't really seal the deal. Many things happen between the click and the actual deployment. Tomcat has a manager webapp that lets you manage the applications deployed. Among other things, their current status is displayed. Have you checked it?

Comment: @user1701467 that could be the problem. web.xml serves as the deployment descriptor for a web app.

Comment: @Tom
No. I don't know where it is. The project worked fine before. I tried to change the `@WebServlet("/place/")` to `@WebServlet({"/place/", "index.jsp"})` and back and that's when I began to get 404s.

Comment: A small piece of advice here, that I've given many times for similar situations - get rid of the Eclipse Tomcat plugin, and deploy your app to a stand-alone Tomcat instance. All of your weird deployment issues will likely be resolved.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek
I installed Tomcat separately from Eclipse. Then I pointed Eclipse to it.

Comment: @user1701467 Keep an eye on it - even with that scenario, I've seen lots of flaky behavior, and lots of people spending a lot of time trying to figure it out. When all else fails, create a .war file and deploy it normall in stand-alone Tomcat. You can still debug from Eclipse that way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding javax.faces-2.1.13.jar to the project fixed the issue.

`http://javaserverfaces.java.net/`